# How to connect a button event to another React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, jsx

I'm learning React and I'm trying to make a simple application: you click on a button and it increments a counter. I've prepared two components, `ClickCounter` and `ClickButton`, but I'm not sure how to connect them together. I've read different tutorials but they expect my components to be Parent/Child - is there something I'm completely missing from a architectural perspective?

```
class ClickCounter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { count: 0 };
  }
  render() {
    return <h1>{this.state.count}</h1>;
  }
}

function ClickButton(props) {
  function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked");
    // increment the ClickCounter..how?
  }
  return (
    <button id="btn" onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
  );
}


function Container() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ClickCounter />
      <ClickButton />
    </div>
  );
}

const root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Container />, root);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common technique for when two sibling components need to share some state is to [lift the state up to the first common ancestor](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) (`Container` in this case) and pass down the state and state-altering functions as props to the children.

**Example**

```js
function ClickCounter(props) {
  return <h1>{props.count}</h1>;
}

function ClickButton(props) {
  return (
    <button id="btn" onClick={props.handleClick}>Click me</button>
  );
}


class Container extends React.Component {
  state = { count: 0 };

  onClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return { count: prevState.count + 1 };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ClickCounter count={this.state.count} />
        <ClickButton handleClick={this.onClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Container />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```